# Why is the top edge rainbowed?

Tags: discussion

Is it because Tim Cook identifies as gay or LGBT awareness month? Or is it for the old Apple logo.
[image: Rainbow Header]

Comment: Reminds me of one of the SO logos now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297866

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not the designer (and certainly won't speak for them), but it could be many reasons starting with Apple's logo from 1977. I actually hope it's many reasons - but does it even matter why?

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.#Logo

Comment: Surely the placement of pixels on the screen matters. When designers answer "why?" their answers, in my experience, are invariably interesting.

Comment: This is correct, it was a reference to the original Apple logo colors. To provide some historical context, it was added in 2011 when Steve Jobs died and it has remained since.